# How to make test case data-driven in robot-framework when using bdd-style?

Tags: robotframework, bdd

I have a BDD-style test case in my robot framework. Which is calling the API. There is a variable in API, which value changes. So I want to write only one test case and want that variable to be changed after one has executed.

Please find the code below:

```
*** Variables ***
   ${Upload_Project_Asset_To_Flagship_API}  /workstream/api/projects/${projectId}/assets/${assetId}/external?debug=1&user_id=${userId}

*** Test Cases ***
TC_01:
    When User Executes Upload Asset To Flagship API
    Then Assert the response after asset upload
    [Teardown]  User gets the uploaded file details

*** Keywords ***
User Executes Upload Asset To Flagship API
${resp}=         Put request  session1  ${Upload_Project_Asset_To_Flagship_API}  headers=${api_header}
```

Comment: BDD and data-driven concepts are incompatible with each other. BDD-style tests typically invoke multiple steps once (given/when/then), whereas data driven tests typically invoke one step multiple times. What do you expect to gain by trying to force a mixture of the two?

Comment: Oh, i didn't knew this. I want to achive that "User Executes Upload Asset To Flagship API" keyword should run based on the parameter "assetId"

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for anyone landing here:
It is perfectly possible to combine Given When Then descriptions with Data driven tests - also in Robot Framework. Many BDD tools (e.g. Cucumber) use a list of "Examples" under the GWEN.
With standard Robot Framework, template tests can be used to list data, but only one template can be used in a suite.
To support Examples in a more natural way, I have written the Robot Framework library RobotFramework-Examples.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30496021)